# What’s the English equivalent of the Danish word “tovholder”?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idiom-requests, danish

I’m looking for something similar to [the Danish word *tovholder*](http://en.bab.la/dictionary/danish-english/tovholder) (literal translation: *rope holder*) which means something like a micro-manager for a single specific task but without the negative connotation that the term *micro-manager* carries with it.

What I would like to express is who is responsible for task X gets done today.

> Martin is (replacement for *tovholder*) for making sure the latest version gets deployed today.

Comment: I don't think there is a term that fits exactly. Something like _coordinator_ is probably just about the closest you'll get.

Comment: "Delegate project manager" ?

Comment: How would you use it in a sentence? I've added an example to the question.

Comment: It doesn't even have to be a single word. I've added the tag phrase-requests

Comment: You might even just say, “Martin is ‘*the  guy*’ for making sure ...

Comment: @Jim That has slightly different connotations. ‘The guy’ implies that he's kind of the ‘go-to guy’ for this kind of thing, whereas _tovholder_ conjures up the image of someone who has taken on (or been given) the task of ‘holding the ropes’ (i.e., taking the reins, managing the different people and aspects involved in some project or task). It's basically a manager, but usually of less officially delineated projects. It's someone who's in charge of organising and coordinating a task that requires some kind of (more or less informal) cooperation between multiple people (the ‘threads/ropes’).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - What about “Martin is point man for making sure...” or *has taken point for*

Comment: Is there a reason it needs to be a noun? *In charge of* or *responsible for* would seem to cover it fairly well: "Martin is *in charge of/responsible for* making sure the latest version gets deployed today."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Responsible*

> Martin is **responsible** for making sure the latest version gets deployed today.

If you need a noun:

> Martin is **the responsible party** (or **the one responsible** for making sure the latest version gets deployed today.

or

> Martin has **the responsibility** (or **the job**) of making sure the latest version gets deployed today.

If you want to vary things up from time to time, Martin could be **in charge of** deploying the latest version.

Answer (score 4):

You could say *"Martin is [spearheading](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/spearhead) getting the latest version deployed today."*

> **2.b.** The driving force in a given action, endeavor, or movement.
>
> **3.** any person or thing that leads or initiates an [...] campaign [...]
>
> **2.** any person, contingent, or force that leads an [...] undertaking [...]

(All three quotes from the linked site, which was citing various other dictionaries - thus the odd numbering.)

A slightly less common phrase could be *"Martin is the [point man](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/point+man) for making sure the latest version gets deployed today."*  Originally a military term (a lead soldier for a patrol, acting as lookout) it has entered the more common vernacular as a generic term for someone at the forefront of an issue.  A similar use would be *"Martin is on point..."*

Comment: _Spearhead_ is good (+1 for that), but I think it implies more initiative and drive than _tovholder_ does. _Tovholder_ does usually imply volunteering for the job, but rarely being the initiator of the project as such. I think _point man_ is a bit too political- and important-sounding to be a really good fit. There's a bit too much representing and being at the forefront of some grand issue, at least in my mind.

Answer (score 3):

On projects I have worked on a common concept is the 'task owner'. I wouldn't say it's common in everyday speech but it's easily understandable outside of that environment and it's unambiguous about where responsibility lies. If there are a number of tasks you might see them grouped together under a project leader who will sometimes be referred to as 'the project lead' - "Who is the project lead for the marketing effort?". But "who is in charge of xxx" is probably more common usage in either case.

Comment: I'm lukewarm on *task owner* but I do like *project lead*.